# List groups with RestFB

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I have this code:

```
        FacebookClient client = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken, Version.LATEST);
        Connection<Group> group = client.fetchConnection("me/groups", Group.class);
        if(!group.getData().isEmpty()){
            Group firstGroup = group.getData().get(0);
            System.out.println(firstGroup.getDescription());
        }
```

Returns `null`, whereas the access token is set to have access to groups.

[image]

What could be wrong with RestFB? I am using version 2.4.0

Comment: not sure if the groups api is back already...

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#groups-4-4

Answer (score 1):

You can get access token with:

```
Login to your facebook
Go to your profile page
Right click to "View Page Source"
Find text with key: "access_token"
```